# Delete storyboard, project still compile

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have a weird problem

I made some changes in storyboard iPad, but the changes weren't effected, so I tried to delete the storyboard, and the project STILL COMPILED.

Anyone tell me why?

Comment: Please Clean / Build the project.

Comment: Yeah, make clean build.